# How to recycle heap memory from HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, heap-memory

This is the first time I am using memory up to limit intentionally, so I am having problem.

```
    HashMap <String, double[]> memory = new HashMap<String, double[]>();

    if ((heapSize/heapMaxSize)<0.9)
        memory.put(address, arr);
```

The number of content to be inserted is infinite, so there is no point of increasing the heap memory size. So I just set the limit to the usage of it up to 90% as it is sufficient for what I want to achieve.

The function with this HashMap is called repeatedly, and my plan was to somehow clean up the heap memory and use the space up to 90% again. But I cannot figure out how to do it. Could somebody enlighten me?

Thank you!

Comment: So are you trying to use this as a cache, basically? If so, I'd use something designed for the job, e.g. http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html

Comment: The answer depends on how you identify the entries that you no longer need, and would be OK to free.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, it does similar thing to cache. I wanted to use hash because of its efficiency and I did not know about Cache api. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I want to simply wipe out everything inside. Not just from the HashMap but also from the memory completely.

Comment: Why, exactly?  Java's GC will take care of that for you automatically when you need more memory.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Somehow it did not...

Comment: In what sense did you "need more memory?". The point of the GC is that it knows better than you what will get the best performance in reality.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got an answer!

memory.clean();

and then triggered garbage collection by

System.gc();

Then it worked!

Comment: And this, dear readers, is why Java's let's-not-deprecate-anything is a bad idea.

Comment: @soc: how does that follow?